# Проблема запуска Python из wine в docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, wine

В контейнер docker (на основе образа ubuntu 20.04), все происходит в Windows 10, установлен wine и в него Python. Есть такая строчка `echo 'wine '\''C:\Python39\python.exe'\'' "$@"' > /usr/bin/python` т.е. при вызове `/usr/bin/python` должен по идее запускаться `C:\Python39\python.exe'`.
Используя `CMD ["/usr/bin/python","/wine/drive_c/Hello.py"]` для проверки запуска получаю ошибку `exec /usr/bin/python: exec format error`.
Где-то встретил, что проблема связана с архитектурой, проверил с помощью `docker image inspect`, получаю `"Architecture": "amd64", "Os": "linux"`. Оно вроде так и должно быть, т.к. брал инсталлятор отсюда `"https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/amd64/${msifile}.msi"`.
В чем может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста?

Часть dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ARG WINE_VERSION=winehq-stable
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.13
ARG PYINSTALLER_VERSION=6.4

RUN set -x \
    && dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get update -qy \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -qfy gpg-agent rename apt-transport-https software-properties-common winbind cabextract wget curl zip unzip xvfb xdotool x11-utils xterm \
    && wget -nv https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key \
    && apt-key add winehq.key \
    && add-apt-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/' \
    && apt-get update -qy \
    && apt-get install --install-recommends -qfy $WINE_VERSION \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && wget -nv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks \
    && chmod +x winetricks \
    && mv winetricks /usr/local/bin

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/wine/gecko
RUN curl -o /usr/share/wine/gecko/wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47/wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi
RUN curl -o /usr/share/wine/gecko/wine_gecko-2.47-x86_64.msi http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47/wine_gecko-2.47-x86_64.msi

ENV WINEARCH win64
ENV WINEDEBUG fixme-all
ENV WINEPREFIX /wine

ENV DISPLAY :0
RUN set -x \
    && echo 'Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1024x768x24 &' >> /root/.bashrc

RUN set -x \
    && winetricks -q win10

ENV PYPI_URL=https://pypi.python.org/
ENV PYPI_INDEX_URL=https://pypi.python.org/simple

RUN set -x \
    && for msifile in `echo core dev exe lib path pip tcltk tools`; do \
        wget -nv "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/amd64/${msifile}.msi"; \
        wine msiexec /i "${msifile}.msi" /qb TARGETDIR=C:/Python39; \
        rm ${msifile}.msi; \
    done \
    && cd /wine/drive_c/Python39 \
    && echo 'wine '\''C:\Python39\python.exe'\'' "$@"' > /usr/bin/python \
    && echo 'wine '\''C:\Python39\Scripts\easy_install.exe'\'' "$@"' > /usr/bin/easy_install \
    && echo 'wine '\''C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe'\'' "$@"' > /usr/bin/pip \
    && echo 'wine '\''C:\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe'\'' "$@"' > /usr/bin/pyinstaller \
    && echo 'wine '\''C:\Python39\Scripts\pyupdater.exe'\'' "$@"' > /usr/bin/pyupdater \
    && echo 'assoc .py=PythonScript' | wine cmd \
    && echo 'ftype PythonScript=c:\Python39\python.exe "%1" %*' | wine cmd \
    && while pgrep wineserver >/dev/null; do echo "Waiting for wineserver"; sleep 1; done \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/easy_install /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pyinstaller /usr/bin/pyupdater \
    && (pip install -U pip || true) \
    && rm -rf /tmp/.wine-*

COPY requirements.txt /wine/drive_c/Python39

RUN cd /wine/drive_c/Python39 \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Иван,  чем обусловлена необходимость использовать версию Pyhon для Windows в Linux, почему вы не используете Pytnon для Linux без Wine?

Comment: Если запустить так `CMD ["/bin/bash", "/usr/bin/python", "/wine/drive_c/Hello.py"]`, то по всей видимости нужный python запускается, однако не совсем как нужно, выдает ошибку _0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The explorer process failed to start."                            
0048:err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
]_

Comment: Иван, вы точно установили Python для Windwos в префиксе .wine. Я создал ради интереса пустой префикс .py64 установил в него Pyhon x64 3.11.8 используя установщик для Windows. Написал меленький скрипт который возвращает мне версию и тип ОС и я получаю однозначные результаты.
Запуск в префиксе:
env WINEPREFIX="/home/ivanovdu/.py64/" WINEARCH=win64 wine python os.py S@> /home/ivanovdu/.py64/py.log - windows 10
запуск в linux:
python3 os.py S@> /home/ivanovdu/.py64/py.log - Debian 12

Comment: Последний ваш вариант запуска стартует версию для Linux естественно он вам говорит что не может создать экземпляр приложения Windows в среде Linux. Вам нужно запустить Python в wine и ваша программа для Windows к моменту запуска должна быть настроена и доступна к запуску в том же префиксе.

Comment: Это проверить не сложно. Судя по всему вы используете префикс по умолчанию. запустите командный процессор "wine cmd" После запуска в командном процессоре выполните команду; "C:\windows\system32>python --version" вывод если все готово к работе
"Python 3.11.8" Иначе вам нужно все сначала настроить. Принцип такой же как в обычной системе ставите все что нужно в префиксе. Нужно понять что в среде интерпретатора свое окружение как в виртуальной машине.

Comment: @Dmitry Ivanov Здравствуйте Дмитрий. Проделал в общем я все манипуляции и результат приводит меня на мысли что это все таки проблема запуска контейнера.
wine cmd мне говорит что все таки я в windows _root@60a54a62cab1:/# wine cmd
Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043_
Далее добавил установленный в wine python в PATH `ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin/python"` и запускаю контейнер уже так `CMD python /wine/drive_c/Hello.py`
И получаю опять же, что я выполняю скрипт в системе windows _Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')_

Comment: @Dmitry Ivanov Но с той же ошибкой _0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded._ Возможно мне нужно как-то указать в запуске контейнера что все нужно выполнять через xvfb??? Правда совсем не понятно как это сделать...

Comment: @Dmitry Ivanov Если же я использую запуск контейнера с python3 (который есть в самой ubuntu) и выполняю тот же скрипт то получаю _Linux-5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
('64bit', '')_

Comment: @Dmitry Ivanov Еще забыл написать что в `wine cmd`  при запросе версии python получаю ровно ту версию, которая и установлена _Z:\>python --version     Python 3.9.13_

Answer (score 1):

Для решения моей задачи, а именно запуск приложения windows, в linux контейнере docker и дальнейшая работа с этим приложением (выполнение python скрипта) понадобилось всего лишь добавить в dockerfile такие строки

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin/python"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xvfb xserver-xephyr
RUN xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1024x768x16 &

CMD xvfb-run -a python /wine/drive_c/script.py
```

Спасибо за обсуждение, помогло найти решение, вернее пойти по нужному пути)))

Comment: забавно ошибка при более внимательном рассмотрении действительно связана с конфликтом  между wine и X11 при попытке создания окна прилоежния в Linux, хотя на первый взгляд похожа на виндовую. В любом случае после проверки вариантов с Python я бы рекомендовал вручную запустить ваше сторнонее приложение, видимо с этого нужно было начать.  Дополните ответ версией рабочего стола для полноты картины. Менше всего я получал проблем в MATE, затем Gnome, самые чудные спецэффекты в kde plasma но они лечатся переходом в сессию X11. Так же рекомендую запустить winecfg и отключить декорирование окон

Comment: @Dmitry Ivanov Здравствуйте) "версия рабочего стола", Дмитрий, а как это посмотреть? И второй вопрос, если не сложно, как отключить вот это "отключить декорирование окон"? У меня нет графического отображения, я могу зайти в контейнер и действовать только с помощью командной строки, но это тоже не особо выход, нужно все сделать в dockerfile))

Comment: Иван, думаю что отсуствие графического интерфейса в вашем случае и стало причиной всех бед, ничего больше делать не нужно, декорровать некому. интересный частный случай.